# Join two tables and Pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Sorry, i'm sure this is a duplicated question, but i don't know how can i search about my problem.
I would like to join two tables (like wordpress post and post_metas) to an third matrix.

I'm using MySQL+PHP

**UPDATE:** 
Thanks for first solutions, I'm looking for the **best** solution. So if not recommended use mysql, you can recommend me another solution on PHP.

I need the most smoother solution. Maybe you can help me find it :)
Thank you guys!

FOODS

```
+----+-----------+
| id | Food name |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Apple     |
|  2 | Banana    |
|  3 | Milk      |
+----+-----------+
```

NUTRITIONS

```
+----+---------+-----------+-------+
| id | food_id |   name    | value |
+----+---------+-----------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | energy    |  1    |
|  2 |       1 | glucose   |  11   |
|  3 |       1 | fructose  |  4    |
|  4 |       2 | energy    |  36   |
|  5 |       2 | glucose   |  112  |
|  6 |       2 | b-vitamin |  67   |
|  7 |       2 | sucrose   |  3    |
|  8 |       3 | fat       |  6    |
|  9 |       3 | calcium   |  66   |
| 10 |       3 | energy    |  77   |
+----+---------+-----------+-------+
```

I would like something like this:

```
+--------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+---------+
|  Food  | energy | glucose | fructose | b-vitamin | sucrose | fat | calcium |
+--------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+---------+
| Apple  |      1 |      11 |        4 |         0 |       0 |   0 |       0 |
| Banana |     36 |     112 |        0 |        67 |       3 |   0 |       0 |
| Milk   |     77 |       0 |        0 |         0 |       0 |   6 |      66 |
+--------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also, this is called pivoting and should be done in your application code

Comment: Why do you need that third matrix?

Comment: I have to print a third table based on first two table.

Comment: That you have to print a third "table" (in a GUI I assume) doesn't mean that you need to get the exact same result in SQL. It's usually easier (especially more flexible and easier to maintain in the future) to fetch raw data and process it in application code as needed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My employer Insists to his very strange solution ideas.. so i have to try all possibilities and test running times because my hands are bounded... What do you recommend me, how should i solve this with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work:

```
select f.foodname,
        max(case when n.name='energy' then value else 0 end)energy,
        max(case when n.name='glucose' then value else 0 end)glucose,
        max(case when n.name='fructose' then value else 0 end)fructose,
        max(case when n.name='b-vitamin' then value else 0 end)b_vitamin,
        max(case when n.name='sucrose ' then value else 0 end)sucrose ,
        max(case when n.name='fat ' then value else 0 end)fat ,
        max(case when n.name='calcium ' then value else 0 end)calcium 
from foods f,
     nutritions n
where f.id=n.food_id     
group by f.foodname
```

Comment: Hm what if i have 1000 different nutrition? This will be slow i think.

Comment: On your comment to Bhavesh: 

SQL is about a fix number of columns. Some databases offer a PIVOT functionality in their SQL, but, as said before, a variable number of columns is against the principles of relational algebra. So you're actually stuck with Bhavesh's answer, I'm afraid ...

Comment: Yes, i told on an another comment: These are my employers requirements. I could design database and webapp so much better, but my employer wants to provide too much freedom to users.. i should go against default principles in this project... He don't care about slowness and security (he asked me disable field validation :DD ).. so i switched myself to slave mode :))